# How i can manage profile settings in Visual Studio Code when I publish an azure function?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have two projects which represent two azure functions in VS Code. When I publish one function to azure, it deleted the other and vice versa after I published each functions.

I find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532959/old-azure-functions-return-after-deleting-and-recreating-publishing-profile-vs-2) but it's a solution for Visual Studio and not for Visual Studio Code, so i'm looking for a solution on VS Code.

I notice, in Visual Studio, that the property i need is (in the Web Deploy.pbxml)

`<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>`

Where i can manage/configure this property in VS Code ?

**EDIT**

The structure of my project :

[image]

And this is what i want ot configure in VS CODE (screenshot from Visual Studio) :

[image]

Comment: What does your file structure look like? VS Code workspaces can mess with deployment settings.

Comment: Hello @Adam, i edit my post with a screenshot of my file structure.

Comment: Is that both of your projects in the screenshot or just one?

Comment: just one, the other has the same file structure

Comment: And if i put all my functions in one project, it seems that it works. It's not what i'm looking for, i would like to have one project per function. In the case of having only one project, how can i deploy only one function ? and not all of them...